# how to un fork the github repository?

Tags: github

How can I un-fork a GitHub repository?

I have never seen `unfork` option - is it possible to do that?

Comment: I think what you can do is either submit a pull request to merge the fork, or delete the forked repository

Comment: It's too easy to fork on Github.  I keep clicking it by mistake when I just want to see what forks there already are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub: make fork an "own project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390249/github-make-fork-an-own-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfork a Github fork without deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326767/unfork-a-github-fork-without-deleting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete forked repo from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302639/delete-forked-repo-from-github)

Comment: Yeah, so many 'forks' are simply a result of an accidental click.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

As of now [Github](https://github.com) doesn't have an unfork option, so the only solution is to delete the forked repo.

> Warning: The following solution will delete your cloned repo.
> If you want unfork without your repo is being deleted try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486339/6335029

**Step 1:** Goto Settings of Repo you want to unfork

**Step 2:** Click Delete this Repository
[image]

**Step 3:** Enter your name / Repo name

**Step 4:** click "I understand the consequences, delete this repository" button

[image]

Comment: This will simply delete the repository. If you want to "unfork" the repository without deleting it, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41486339/2546416

Comment: Yeah, this deletes the repo. Don't do this!

Comment: This is an answer to a totally different question.  It should not be marked as the solution.

Comment: @Michael, you never find the unfork option in GitHub, so if you want unfork a repo you should delete it, that's why it marked as the solution.

Comment: @NaveenDA The linked answer is the correct one.  Then you proceed to explain how to delete a repo.  Deleting the repo is not the answer.  If the question asked was "how do I delete a repo?", this would be the answer.  Add the other steps, and then I'm on board.

Comment: @Michael even the linked answer is also to delete the repo, but they don't give steps to delete, so I decided to give that steps( FYI: 62 people likes this answer)

Comment: @NaveenDA Check out Tiago's response

Comment: @Michael that also delete your repo "Delete original repository in https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/settings"

Comment: @NaveenDA It does, but then it creates the new unforked repo which is what's missing here.

Comment: @Michael, Yeah but how can you say "it is a totally different answer" when you delete the repo which also meant you unfork the repo.

Comment: @NaveenDA You are missing steps in unforking a repo.  All you showed is how to delete a repo.  As mikecousins accurately stated, if all you did was follow your directions, you would no longer have your repo!  That's why you need the rest of the steps to make this a good answer so someone doesn't just lose their work.

Comment: That's why I provide Warning at the beginning.

Comment: If you want to retain anything (or everything) of your repo, simply contact GitHub support about detaching your fork. They will do so no questions asked since it is a common request.

Comment: @NaveenDA Step one should be "Clone or copy your repo". You've done a really good job of drawing peoples eyes to the clear and simple instructions, but are putting novice users at risk by placing the warning *outside* of those instructions in a block quote. This is terrible UX. I wonder how many people have had to pray afterwards that they had a clone at all, nevermind a recent one. Or have had to go hunt down a clone from a colleague. What if a user has never cloned the repo at all, and only made edits of the fork in github? Work gone. Poof.

Comment: Okay I will add

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan All the answer are in creative commons license in Stackoverflow. Still, we can create a compliant on StackOverflow meta

Comment: Forking creates a copy of repository. Undoing a fork means deleting that copy. So simple is that, a pity that option to revert false click is so hidden. I don't understand why so many folks doesn't understand word 'undo' on purpose. +1 for great answer.

Answer (score 55):

GitHub support can do this for you.

1. Go to this link https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-forks
2. Type in "unfork"
3. Let the virtual assistant help you

They completed the process for me within 1 minute after that.

Comment: In the absence of a feature to do this, this is pretty cool.

Comment: I have tried this didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for me, pretty impressive.

Answer (score 22):

#### Option 1: Rename, import, delete

1. Rename your old fork (e.g. `repo.old`)
2. Import your old fork as a new repo (Note: provide the `https://` or `git://` URI of the old fork)
3. Delete / archive the old fork

Note: the "import" option is an option when creating stuff:

[image: "Import repository"]

#### Option 2: Clone, delete, create, push

1. Back up your repo! E.g. `git clone` to your local file system.
2. Delete the original repo from GitHub ([See the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831402/781938)...)
3. Create a new repo with the same name
4. Push your local backup to the new GitHub repo

I recommend option 1.

Whatever you do, back up your work! Especially if you follow the other answer, which just tells you to delete your repo...

Comment: Honestly I though they had the unfork functionality....... but yeah, this is a valid more verbose way of doing so :)

Answer (score 8):

## Unfork *without* deleting the repository

1. Go to this link https://support.github.com/request?q=unfork
2. Click on *"Our virtual assistant can help with detaching/unforking a repository"*
   [image: screenshot]
3. Click **Detach**
   [image: screenshot]
4. It will ask for the Repository link
5. Done.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do it via the web portal (without cloning/deleting the repo as described in other responses). I put in a request to GitHub support, asking them to convert the repository to 'normal mode', and they did it within five minutes.

Comment: They did it in 5 minutes for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can always send in a ticket and have GH support detach it from the fork network for you. That way you keep the followers, issues, etc.

Comment: Are you sure GH provides this action as a service in support actions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Can you file a ticket and request this? Yes, as other people have confirmed. You may need permission from the root owner.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, follow these steps:

1- First go to the parent project anf change it's visibility
2- Then do same with the child project

3- Then revert all repositories to thein initial state of visibility.

This worked for me. I hope same for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).