# How to not see an old GitHub repo anymore

Tags: github

In my list of repos I have an old repo that I worked on for 1 hr.

I would like to not see it anymore, I would like to not be involved with it anymore, I want it off of my screen.

How do I do it?

Here is a screen of my repo list:

[image: Github print-screen]

Comment: Are you looking to delete the repository? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14860631/899126

Comment: I really don't like github, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [delete the repo](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/). That will completely remove it though, not only from that list. You won't be able to access it again.

You might want to save of backup first if there is any chance you will want to access it later, especially if the work you did hasn't been pushed into the project that you forked it from.

You can delete a repo by going to the "Settings" page for that repo (click on the repo in that list and "Settings" is a tab on the next page), then scrolling all the way to the bottom and clicking on "Delete this repository".

Comment: Chris Florence answered question. Thank you for your help Paulpro.

Comment: Well, now the repo shows up in a new place... Deleting the repo just moved it over to the list of "Repositories you contribute to", can i remove my self from it?

Comment: Paulpro said: "That will completely remove it though, not only from that list. You won't be able to access it again."  I am still on it even after deleting it I can still browse it.

Comment: @DonMoore You must be browsing the repository that you forked, not the one you deleted. You can't delete that one, as it is owned by someone else (the user: phpassessment)

Comment: @DonMoore You have an [open pull request for that repo](https://github.com/phpassessment/gitbasics/pull/3), that is why it is considered a repository that you contribute to. I don't think there is any way to cancel that. Only phpassessment can close it.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That is good enough. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting to ask is how to delete a GitHub repository.
Deleting a repository as @Paulpro rightly said will remove all your data from the given account so if you need any data it will be wise to take a backup.

How to delete a Github Account:

1. Login to your Github Account
2. Open the repository you wish to delete
3. On the menu of Repository click on Settings (the menu contains commits, settings, contributors etc.The last tab is settings there.)
4. Scroll down to the very bottom, the last option will be delete repository, click on that
5. In a confirmation box that comes enter the repository name as it is and then confirm to delete the repository.

**Note** These steps are to delete a repository.If you just wish to hide a repository from the public you will need a private repository option which requires a paid Github Account.

Comment: Hope this helps if any more details needed or any issues with the answer please let me know.Thank You