# I have a fork for a repo in gitHub.com - how can I delete it

Tags: git, github

I have a fork juandent/vcpkg which was created from microsoft/vcpkg. I want to ****erase/delete this fork**** so I can create a new one fresh from microsoft/vcpkg at the github.com site for that repo.
I do not want to keep any commits I had done on my fork, just get that fork *identical* to microsoft/vcpkg so I can add a simple change and then propose that to be merged into microsoft/vcpkg.
How can this be done?

Regards,
Juan

Comment: You mean something like this: [Delete forked repo from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302639/delete-forked-repo-from-github)?

Comment: If you want to delete the fork, just do it through the GitHub UI (Settings -> Delete this repo).